# Make inline-block divs appear underneath instead of overlapping

Tags: html, css, position

HTML:

```
<div id="parent">
    <div class="child1">
        <img src="img/top.png"/>
    </div>
    <div class="child2">
        <img src="img/middle.png"/>
    </div>
    <div class="child3">
        <img src="img/bottom.png"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.child1{
    display: inline-block;
}
.child2{
    display: inline-block;
}
.child3{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

I have the display set to inline-block because I want the divs to fit the size of the image that they contain (different size for each). However, when I have it set up this way, they appear one after another from left to right. I would like them to be stacked, where child2 is directly below child1 and child3 is directly below child2.

Thanks

Comment: Can you share screenshot of your code and front-end screen ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give each child `div` `width:100%` and give the `#parent` div `text-align:center`

```css
#parent {
  text-align: center;
}

#parent>div {
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div class="child1">
    <img src="http://dingo.care2.com/pictures/greenliving/uploads/2013/10/cat-with-stunning-green-eyes.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div class="child2">
    <img src="http://www.top13.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/cat-photography-zoran-milutinovic-Fluffy-The-King.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div class="child3">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/D2cqjmO.jpg" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

### Solve using flexbox

```css
#parent {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div class="child1">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200" alt="random">
  </div>
  <div class="child2">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/600/200" alt="random">
  </div>
  <div class="child3">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200" alt="random">
  </div>
</div>
```

---

If you really want to make divs elements to fit exactly the size of its contained image, then you must remove empty spaces or set `font-size: 0` on parent's container (or child divs)

Check this [pen](https://codepen.io/carloluis/pen/POaWRy)

Answer (score 0):

Update your css like this

```
.child1{
    float:left;
    clear:both;
}
.child2{
   float:left;
    clear:both;
}
.child3{
    float:left;
    clear:both;
}
```